How to bind ktor to a unix socket?
I can't find a way to bind ktor server to a Unix socket, whatever engine I use. I've found the socket API, but I cant find a way to have ktor handle requests coming from it as it would with plain HTTP request.
I've tried Netty and Tomcat without success, they seem to lack the ability to bind to Unix socket when bundled into ktor (Tomcat seems to be supposed to).

Unfortunately, that's impossible at the moment, please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-4766. Only the ktor-network module allows binding UNIX domain sockets.
